# Get the Integer from the end of a string (variable length)

Tags: java

I have a string of a variable length and at the end of the string are some digits. What would be the best / efficient way, to parse the string and get the number from the end as an Integer?

The String and the digits at the end can can be of any length. For example:

```
abcd123 --> 123
abc12345 --> 12345
ab4cd1 --> 1
```

Comment: I see you are new. When you like an answer, you have to accept it, so there appears a green tick. That finishes your question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something along the line of:

```
final static Pattern lastIntPattern = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]+([0-9]+)$");
String input = "...";
Matcher matcher = lastIntPattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String someNumberStr = matcher.group(1);
    int lastNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(someNumberStr);
}
```

could do it.

This isn't necessary the "most efficient" way, but unless you have a critical bottleneck around this code (as: extract int from millions of String), this should be enough.

Comment: For performance, I would move outside the pattern compilation, which can occur only once.

Comment: For performance, I would not use regexp at all. It is a powerful feature, but the task mentions "most efficient way".

Comment: @Eyal: agreed. I have updated the answer to use a `static final` variable for the pattern.

Comment: @Max: agreed, I have added a caveat to the answer.

Comment: This fails if the String at the beginning is empty (OP specified that they could be any length), such as the String `"135"`.

Answer (score 16):

Other solutions provided here are fine, so I'll provide this one just to be a bit different:

```
public static BigInteger lastBigInteger(String s) {
    int i = s.length();
    while (i > 0 && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i - 1))) {
        i--;
    }
    return new BigInteger(s.substring(i));
}
```

- It manually looks for the position of the last non-`Character.isDigit(char)`

  - It still works if the input is all digit
- It uses `BigInteger`, so it can handle really large numbers at the end of really long strings.

  - Use `Integer.parseInt` or `Long.parseLong` if either sufffice

Comment: This one throws NumberFormatException when s is empty or contains no digits. The requirements for the function does not specify the behavior for these cases, so I guess you can get away with it :)

Comment: Thanks polygenelubricants! Your method was helpful. I had a series of strings which may or may not have had numbers at the end, and I wanted to sort them based on the number if present. I used your method, but before I did, I appended "0" to the end of the strings I was comparing. After using your method for each string I was comparing, if I got zeros back, I know there were no numbers and just compared strings. If I got any numbers other than zero, I compared the integers.

Answer (score 4):

Best is such a subjective term :-) Unless you're going to being doing this quite a bit (in which case performance may take priority over readability), I'd just go with my first gut feeling:

```
int n = 0;
try {
    n = Integer.parseInt (str.replaceFirst("^.*\\D",""));
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: I *feel* that a `find()` call is much more appropriate here than a `replaceAll()`. Also: your code will fail with the input `"ab4cd1"`.

Comment: It shouldn't fail with that input since the match is greedy. It will find up to the last non-numeric.

Comment: @Joachim: no it won't; `*` is greedy. It will assign `1` to `n` as expected. Unless you're talking about some other problem.

Comment: Blame Josh Bloch; he's the first to have discovered it.

Answer (score 3):

```
int getTrailingInteger(String str)
{
    int positionOfLastDigit = getPositionOfLastDigit(str);
    if (positionOfLastDigit == str.length())
    {
        // string does not end in digits
        return -1;
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(str.substring(positionOfLastDigit));
}

int getPositionOfLastDigit(String str)
{
    int pos;
    for (pos=str.length()-1; pos>=0; --pos)
    {
        char c = str.charAt(pos);
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) break;
    }
    return pos + 1;
}
```

Comment: The class `Char` doesn't exists! It should be `Character`

Comment: Yes.  Of course you are correct.  The code has been edited to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, this is the most optimized way. I've just wanted to post the same solution but Aeth outperformed me :P
However, this can only be used if the number is not encoded somehow (scientific representation will fail for example).

Comment: @Max, "at the end of the string are some digits" seems to discount scientific notation so I wouldn't concern myself with that.

Comment: Second mark: It should be `Integer.parseInt(...)` and not `Integer.parse(...)`

Comment: @Aeth: Only two. :-) Maybe it sounds a bit aggressive, but it isn't meant like that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to do this without regex!

### Check out my update!

```
public static int getLastInt(String line)
{
    int offset = line.length();
    for (int i = line.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        char c = line.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c))
        {
            offset--;
        }
        else
        {
            if (offset == line.length())
            {
                 // No int at the end
                 return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            }
            return Integer.parseInt(line.substring(offset));
        }
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(line.substring(offset));
}
```

This works perfect.

Comment: It works, but it is not optimized. Concatenating strings is very heavy-load operation in Java. Much better solution is just to calculate the offset, and then get the substring by that offset.

Comment: @Max: I improved it. Now he first searches the offset. Then substring

Answer (score 1):

```
private int intAtEnd(String string) {
        int i, j;
        i = j = string.length();
        while (--i > 0) {
            if (Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))) continue;
            i++;
            break;
        } 
        if (j - i > 1) return Integer.parseInt(string.substring(i));
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: This answer throws an exception on "d135". It doesn't handle a single character as the name followed by a number.  I think you need `while (--i >= 0)` and to change your last `if` to `if (i > 0 && len - i > 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getIntFromEndOfString(String inpStr){
    int revVal = 0;
    boolean flag = false;
    String reverseNo  = "", result = "";
    for (int i = inpStr.length()-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        reverseNo = String.valueOf(inpStr.charAt(i));
        if(!flag)
        if(reverseNo.equals("0") ||reverseNo.equals("1") || reverseNo.equals("2") || reverseNo.equals("3")
                | reverseNo.equals("4") || reverseNo.equals("5") || reverseNo.equals("6") || reverseNo.equals("7")
                || reverseNo.equals("8") || reverseNo.equals("9")){
            revVal = Integer.parseInt(reverseNo);
            result+= String.valueOf(revVal);
        }else{
            inpStr = result;
            i = inpStr.length();
            flag = true;
            result = "";
        }else{
            result += reverseNo;
        }
    }
    revVal = Integer.parseInt(result);
    return revVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already many good answers, I just wanted to give my two cents.

I know running **parseInt()** in a loop is not an efficient way but for sake of **simplicity**.

```
public static int getIntFromEnd (String string) {
  for (int a = string.length()-1; a >=0; a--)
  try {
    int result = Integer.parseInt(string.substring(a,string.length()));
    // the whole string is integer
    if(a == 0) return result;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // there is no numbers at the end
    if(a == string.length()-1) break;
    return Integer.parseInt(string.substring(a+1,string.length()));
  }
  // there is no numbers
  return -1;
}
```

***TESTED AGAINST OTHER ANSWERS:***

I have run some tests against **the accepted answer**, and this code runs **7 to 10 times faster**.

Then I tried it against **the second most upvoted answer**, and this code runs **3 to 4 times faster**.

Comment: Interesting, but wouldn't this be faster the for loop started {a} pointing at the last character in the string, tried to parse it, and continue the for loop until the try fails. The last parsed number is the correct value. Then long strings would not impact your run-time.

Comment: @ScottK Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each character looking for non-numeric characters. When one is found chop it and everything off before it. After the loop has run cast the result to int.

Answer (score 0):

In general I prefer clear and short code, but if performance is really your first priority here, consider something like:

```
private static int getNum(String s){
    int res = 0;
    int p = 1;
    int i = s.length()-1;
    while(i >= 0){
        int d = s.charAt(i) - '0';
        if (d>=0 && d<=9)
            res += d * p;
        else
            break;
        i--;
        p *= 10;
    }

    return res;     
}
```

It doesn't use any complex string/regex operations.
But again - if performance is not an issue, please use the other techniques presented above.

Comment: There is one nice function: Character.isDigit(char)